# HP Pavilion battery charging "bolt" LED light flashing at 82%

Tags: battery, hp-pavilion

A few days ago, my HP Pavilion dv-1413us battery charging "bolt" LED light started flashing and it would not charge the battery until full (stops at 94%). I unpluged it and used battery, and now it only charges to 82%. What is wrong with it? I've tried the power reset [here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-e-g-Windows-8/Battery-charge-light-blinking/td-p/707229), but it still wouldn't charge fully. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your battery has built up a memory. It will continue to degrade until it will not hold a charge. Your best and most likely only option is to replace the battery.